SLAM with multiple ultrasonic sensors
My question is this: I have a robot on wheels and it has two ultrasonic sensors in the front and back, I have them stored in URDF and I can visualize them in rviz2 and Gazebo, but when I thought that I need to use these sensors to for example create a map in SLAM or future to go around objects to go to some point I realized that SLAM in its . yaml file can only refer to one top, and it was referring to my Lidar, but I have 4 topics for each of my sonar sensors, is there any way to refer to all my sensors at once so it can take into account the data from them to create a map in SLAM and then unique objects in NAV2 for example when it is in motion thanks to 4 sensors.
I've tried searching for a possibly similar problem but I haven't found a solution, what I've seen is "it's a difficult task" or something like that, I've tried creating a topic to combine all the topics into one, but I don't think that's quite right because it would have to use the average of all the sensors, I don't have any ideas yet.
